# How can I change Google App Engine Deployment from Standard to Flex in IntelliJ

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-code

I installed the Cloud Code Plugin for IntelliJ to deploy a Java 8 project to App Engine (Standard)

I added the Framework Support by running:

> Tools > Cloud Code > App Engine > Add App Engine Support > Google App Engine Standard

Now I have to change this to App Engine Flexible but when I try to do this the same way as for App Engine Standard I get the following error:

> All modules already have App Engine support, or no modules were found.

What files do I have to modify or how can I remove App Engine support and start over?

I already tried right-clicking the project and selecting `Add Framework support...`but the Google App Engine option isn't checked and when I select it doesn't give me any options

Comment: a couple things to check: 1) when you got to Project Structure -> Facets. Do you already see a `Google App Engine Standard` facet? 2) What does your module and artifact structure look like, under Project Settings (this will help me debug the problem). Also feel free to post an issue on our issue tracker: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of this issue is that in IntelliJ you cannot add child framework support when parent is already added. What this means is that since you have your application running under the standard environment you are unable to add in an additional environment (in this case, the app engine flexible).
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000073610-Cannot-add-child-framework-support-when-parent-is-already-added

I ran into the same error as the one stated in your situation. You can simply import the project again from your project directory and select the framework (App Engine Flexible) instead of the standard environment.